# What is the canonical way to check for approximate zeros in Catch2?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++14, catch2, floating-point-comparison

**What is the canonical way to compare to approximate zeros in Catch2?**

I found this way given a tolerance of 1e-12, but it is not clear it is the best way:

```
TEST("a approx. equal to b", "[test]"){
    REQUIRE( a - b == (0_a).margin(1e-12) );
}
```

I am not asking how to compare floats in general. I know that is not a simple problem. I am asking how to use Catch2 given a certain tolerance known in advance.

What follows didn't work, because relative (epsilon) errors do not behave well near zero:

```
TEST("a approx. equal to b", "[test]"){
    REQUIRE( a - b == (0_a).epsilon(1e-5) );
}
```

---

Other possible (not so nice)( alternatives seem to be

```
TEST("a approx. equal to b", "[test]"){
    REQUIRE( std::abs( a - b ) < 1e-12 );
}
```

```
TEST("a approx. equal to b", "[test]"){
    REQUIRE_THAT( a - b, WithinULP(0., ???));
}
```

```
TEST("a approx. equal to b", "[test]"){
    REQUIRE_THAT( a, WithinULP(b, ???));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(a == Approx(b).margin(1e-12))
```

[From the Catch2 GitHub](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/projects/SelfTest/UsageTests/Approx.tests.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

[Catch is now recommending matchers, rather than approx.](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/comparing-floating-point-numbers.md) Like:

`REQUIRE_THAT(a, WithinAbs(b, 1e-12));`